# Webkit fullscreen mode work wrong with tabCapture API

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I use tabCapture to share audio of tab, the fullscreen mode works wrong. Here is tabCapture:

```
chrome.tabCapture.capture({audio: true}, function(t) {
...
});
```

When I call `webkitRequestFullScreen()` of video element, the video only fit to browser window (not full screen).
Is this a bug of Chrome?

Comment: The way I understand  [chrome.tabCapture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabCapture) is that 'fullscreen' is of boolean type and it's job is only to return whether the screen is on fullscreen or not. It's not supposed to SET the screen to fullscreen mode.

Comment: No, it is chromium bug. This only happens from Chrome 55+.

Comment: You can open an [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new) if it's indeed a bug.

Comment: Yes, I already reported to Chromium team.